# Appending an array and storing values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import array
a=[]
count = 0
while True:
    i=int(input("A number "))
    count = count + 1
    for j in range (0, count):
        a.append(i)
    if (count==3):
        break
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

This appears when I prompt the program to print 'a' variable where I want 'a' to store values like

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Can someone point out what's wrong with my code

Comment: its because of your for loop you are appending that number n, n times

Comment: If you don't want them repeated then don't use a for loop to repeat them? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @JonClements Let me check on that then I'll tell you

Comment: Why do you `import array` when you don't use it? You are using a list, and that's probably what you *should* use.

Comment: isn't  ".append()" a function of array module? I just saw it while going through the docs of python and I saw it there so I just imported array as a whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code, is that you add `input number` to the `a` one more time in each `while` iteration. It's the fault of `for` loop there.
Also, you don't have to import `array`.
Also, the if/break combo is redundant, just set iterations in the `while` loop.

Try this code:

```
a = []
count = 0

while count < 3:
    i = int(input("A number: "))
    a.append(i)
    count += 1

print(a)
```

Variable A prints:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use append but in a different way:

```
a = []
count = 0
while True:
 a.append(input("A number "))
 count += 1
 if count == 3:
  break
```

in your code you're appending the user's number 'count' times to a[], the way i did it, it will append one time for loop.

You can also use

```
for x in range(0,3)
 a.append(input('A number'))
```

it work's as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `for` loop:

```
a=[]
count = 0
while count < 3:
    count += 1
    a.append(int(input("A number ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for duplicate values in your list, **a**, is the inner **for** loop. To illustrate with an example, consider what happens when you have already entered **1** as the input and now enter **2** as the input. At this moment, before your code begins executing the for loop, **count** has the value **2**. The inner for loop will thus insert your input value, stored in variable **i** (in this case, 2), twice. Similarly, when you input **3**, **count** has the value **3** and hence the inner for loop will execute three times.

The correct code should be as follows :

```
import array
a=[]
count = 0
while True:
    i=int(input("A number "))
    count = count + 1
    if (count==3):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for-loop or simply do

```
a=[]
count=3
for i in range(count):
  a.append(int(input("new number: ")))
```

Importing array isn't needed here.
And a little hint (if you don't allready know): `i+=1` is the same as `i=i+1`

Answer (score 0):

By playing the answer from deshu, you might also consider to use try and except so that the user could continue to type a number and prompt him if ever he enter non-numeric character.

```
a = []
count = 0

while count < 3:
    try:
        i = int(input("A number: "))
        a.append(i)
        count += 1
    except:
        print('Enter only a whole number.')

print(a)
```